# C# .net -> SQLite error: Unable to open the database file

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm getting "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Unable to open the database file." when I attempt to access the database to save a record upon the "first" opening of my program.

Here's the thing, it works fine when debugging locally in Visual Studio, but stops working when I package the program in an installer, and then install the program somewhere.

I was guessing that it was the location of the database, which I just have set at database.s3db without a path, because it is stored next to the program's exe, but how could that cause problems?

I'm at a loss, any further ideas or suggestions for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are installing the program in a folder which the user doesn't have write permissions so cannot modify the database file.

Comment: That was exactly it. Why is it that ProgramFiles has places that can't be modified? Don't most programs modify their own files?

Comment: @CODe, no, starting from Windows Vista only the administrator have write permissions to the program files folder. You have to use the corresponding `c:\users\AccountName` folder to store user specific files.

Comment: ´Why is it that ProgramFiles has places that can't be modified?´
In order to make it more difficuilt for malware (virus, trojan) to install itself

Comment: @CODe: I strongly disagree - this is actually one of the few things MS got right in Vista and subsequent versions. UNIX-like systems have been allowing regular users write access only to their home directories by default since forever, and that is a Good Thing. It prevents malicious software from doing Bad Stuff and dumb users from doing Dumb Stuff.

Comment: If the database is to be shared among all users of a system, you can put it in the All Users Application Data folder.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your DataSource Format like this :

`@"C:\Users\Mehmeto\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\......\bin\myDB.sqlite";`

Where the directory points to where your project is located.